# Evenly align and make responsive for dropdown lists HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a few options laid out on HTML with dropdown lists, using the 'select' tag. I want to make them responsive so that when the screen is resized, it will slowly stack on top of each other evenly. Right now, it is somewhat responsive, but it is not aligning evenly. I want to make all the titles and the dropdown lists evenly aligned. I tried to do:

```
text-align: right;
float: left;
padding: 5px;
margin-top: 10px;
```

but this does not solve the problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

So the top should have 'home type' and 'address'; 2nd row should have 'age range' and 'clubs' and 'payment type'; then last row should have 'start date' and 'end date' when it is full screen. Each dropdown list should align evenly (so for example, home type dropdown would align with age range and start date; address would align with clubs and end date; and age range would be aligned by itself at the end)

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q3h0qkhm/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this what you expected right.

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div id="home" class="form-group"> Home Type:
      <select id="homeDDL" class="form-control">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div id="address" class="form-group"> Address:
      <select id="addressDDL" class="form-control">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div id="age" class="form-group"> Age Range:
      <select id="ageDDL" class="form-control">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div id="clubs" class="form-group"> Clubs:
      <select id="clubsDDL" class="form-control">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div id="pay" class="form-group"> Payment Type:
      <select id="payDDL" class="form-control">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div id="startDate" class="form-group"> Start Date:
      <input type="text" id="StartDate" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div id="endDate" class="form-group"> End Date:
      <input type="text" id="EndDate" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding width:320px; to your divs. That tidies everything up a lot.

```
text-align: right;
float: left;
padding: 5px;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 320px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this fashion -

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added labels for each select tag and added CSS to this so all the labels are the same width.

CSS:

```
.row label{width: 100px; float: left; margin-right: 10px;}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/88sr5wfk/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just add height and width into your .row

```
.row{
 width:100%;
 height:120px;
}
```

This keeps home and address at top, then age,club,payment and last start date & end date. To reduce spacing below them in that stage just reduce height of .row